# Connecting bootstrap dropdown to object and loop with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, loops, drop-down-menu

This time I tried to make a code which lets user choose the location where he/she wants to go. I've wrote html and js but now I've been stuck (about half a day...) by connecting them. 
I have written a dropdown menu with help of bootstrap. I have also written a js file which should loop those locations. Finally it should understand what user has choosen and then output the result which should be:

`var text = '<p>' + buses[i].to + '<br> - Distance from Estonia: ' + buses[i].distance + ' km <br> - Price: ' + buses[i].price + ' euros <br>'`

In web browser something like this:

Amsterdam

- Distance from Estonia: 2000 km
- Price: 250 euros

But whatever I try, nothing works (I know it's because of my poor knowledge, i don't blame JS). I have tried to put "id" and "onclick function" everywhere.

So, I'll paste a little part of it, maybe someone could help :)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Buses</h2> 

<p id="test1">...</p>
<p id="test2">...</p>

<script src="js/buses.js"></script>


<!-- Dropdown menu for beautiful usage -->

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu2" type="button">
    List of locations
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <ul id="boss">
      <li><a role="button" onclick="bus()" value="Amsterdam">">Amsterdam</a></li>
      <li><a role="button" onclick="bus()" value="Madrid">Madrid</a></li>
      <li><a role="button" onclick="bus()" value="Stockholm">Stockholm</a></li>
      <li><a role="button" onclick="bus()" value="Riga">Riga</a></li>  
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And my JS file:

```
// If person is in some location

document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = "<hr> You're in Estonia, where would You want to travel?";

function bus() {

// Object with info     
    var buses = [
  { to: 'Amsterdam', distance: 2000, price: 250},
  { to: 'Madrid', distance: 4500, price: 350},
  { to: 'Stockholm', distance: 1500, price: 90},
  { to: 'Riga', distance: 400, price: 100}
  ];

// Should get result which user has choosen
    var res = document.getElementById("boss");
    var result = res.value;
    console.log(value); // outputs html row... >.>

// Loop through the object
    var text = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < (buses.length); i++) {   

    if (result == buses[i].to) { text = '<p>' + buses[i].to + '<br> - Distance from Estonia: ' + buses[i].distance + ' km <br> - Price: ' + buses[i].price + ' euros <br>';
    alert("Works!!!!"); // Well, last thing is to change it to output "var text" result
    }

    };
    document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = text; // If everything is correct, this should output sentence about selected bus
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the value of the city in onclick function itself

```
<li><a role="button" onclick="bus('Amsterdam')">Amsterdam</a></li>
```

And in function receive it like this

```
function bus(value) {
var result=value;
}
```

Comment: I can't believe it was so easy... Thanks! :)